# Change of variables in QCLP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, change-of-variable, qclp, second-order-cone-programming

Is there any change of variables that makes the following optimization problem easier to solve?

\begin{align}
\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n,t\in\mathbb{R}}\quad & c^\top x,\\
\mbox{s.t.}\quad\quad &  ax+b\geq t,\\
& x^\top P x\leq t^2,\\
& x^\top Q x\leq 1,\\
& t\geq 0.
\end{align}

where matrices $Q,P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are positive definite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constraints are convex. The problem is convex, and can be formulated and solved as a Second Order Cone Problem (SOCP), for which there are many high quality solvers.

In CVX under MATLAB, this can be formulated as

```
cvx_begin
variable x(n) t
maximize(c''*x)
a*x + b >= t
norm(chol(P)*x) <= t
norm(chol(Q)*x) <= 1
t >= 0
cvx_end
```